# Haskell - Passing a variable to a sub-function

Tags: haskell

I have a function `main`, which has a sub-function `menu`. In `main`, I load a file, ask for the user to input their name, then call `menu` to display a menu. After each action in the menu has been completed, I'm going to call `menu` again until an exit condition is met.

I'm having trouble passing the file I'm loading in `main` into `menu` - I want to perform an action on the database for each command.

This is my code so far (i've cut out bits that are irrelevant):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do contents <- readFile "myfile.txt"
          let finalDatabase = (read contents :: [Film])
          putStr "Please enter your name: "
          name <- getLine
          menu finalDatabase
          where menu db = do putStrLn "Please select an option:"
                             putStrLn "1: Display all films"
                             putStr "Choice: "
                             choice <- getLine
                             case choice of {
                                 "1" -> displayAll db;
                             }
                             menu
```

The `displayAll` function just prints out a Database nicely.

I'm getting the following error in WinHugs:

```
ERROR file:.\films.hs:152 - Type error in function binding
*** Term           : menu
*** Type           : [([Char],[[Char]],Int,[[Char]])] -> IO a
*** Does not match : IO a
```

I thought that if I didn't specify a line like `menu :: Database -> IO ()`, it would accept any parameters without being concerned with their type.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:
Stupid mistake, I just forgot to pass the database when calling menu again after the case statement!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no, not specifying a type, does not mean that the function will accept any type. **It means that the type will be inferred**.

The reason that you're getting that particular type error is that at the end of `menu`'s `do` block, you write `menu`, which is a function and not a value of type `IO`. I'm not exactly sure why you do that. If you want to create an infinite loop, you should change the last call to `menu db`, instead of returning the function unapplied. If you don't want an infinite loop, I don't see why you use `menu` at the end at all.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the inferred type. Yeah, I'd missed off the parameter when calling menu again. I am going to change it eventually to check for a condition before calling `menu db`

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that if I didn't specify a line like `menu :: Database -> IO ()`, it would accept any parameters without being concerned with their type.

That's not true, in your case `menu` really has the type `Database -> IO ()` so in the last line before the `where`, you need to give it a `Database` to get an `IO ()` - probably `db` (as in `menu db`) but maybe later, you'll start modifying the database and then you can pass the new one in. Haskell doesn't just look around at what's in scope to find a suitable value of type `Database`!

If the database truly is fixed you don't need to pass it in and you could use something like:

```
main = do contents <- readFile "myfile.txt"
       let finalDatabase = (read contents :: [Film])
       putStr "Please enter your name: "
       name <- getLine
       menu
       where menu = do putStrLn "Please select an option:"
                       putStrLn "1: Display all films"
                       putStr "Choice: "
                       choice <- getLine
                       case choice of {
                           "1" -> displayAll finalDatabase -- instead of db
                       }
                       menu
```

But, as said, that's going to break when you start modifying the 'database'. Let's say you define a function `doSomethingWithDatabaseDependingOnChoice :: String -> [Film] -> IO [Film]` which takes the choice and the old database, performs some in/output and returns a new database, you could use it as follows:

```
      <same as before>
      menu finalDatabase
      where menu db = do putStrLn "Please select an option:"
                         putStrLn "1: Display all films"
                         putStr "Choice: "
                         choice <- getLine
                         newDb <- doSomethingWithDatabaseDependingOnChoice choice db
                         menu newDb
```

Another option would be to use implicit parameters, but I'm guessing that's a bit too advanced at the moment!

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. Yeah, doing an introductory haskell/functional programming unit at the moment so you're right about the implicit parameters being a bit advanced!